# Pycharm not recognizing installed BeautifulSoup4 module

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I have trouble with Pycharm recognizing installed modules. I'm using Pycharm 2018.2.4 CE with Python 3.7 x64, on Windows 10. I don't have Python 2.x installed. I installed requests and BeautifulSoup4 from command line using 'pip' and 'pip3' commands. Pip list and Pycharm is seeing installed module in interpreters list but when I enter my code is grayed out like none of those were installed:

[Grayed out code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkjrw.png)

[Interpreter settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YeOb.png)

I tried everything - reinstalling both Python (x64 and x86) and Pycharm, installing/upgrading/uninstalling BeautifulSoup4 and bs4, I also tried every solution I could find on stack or google, seems like few people had similar issue but no one gave them any final answer. Does anyone know how to fix this under Windows 10?

Comment: It's `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` from [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this helps:

Go to the following path:

```
File/ Settings/ Project: Project_Name/ Project Interpreter
```

Click on the plus sign on the right, find the module there and install it.

Also, if they are gray, it's because you have imported them but haven't used them yet. The only one which might have a problem is the last one with the red lines maybe.

This was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52469365/7277561)

Also, below should be changed

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Right, so that enabled bs4 but it's not importing BeautifulSoup4 (it's underlined in gray). Now this is the moment I'm trying to replicate from my work station. Is BeautifulSoup4 working under Pycharm at all? Sorry for newbish questions!

Comment: Try this:    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: God, removing 4 from BeautifulSoup finally helped. Thanks a lot!